# How to manipulate the following text

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed, awk

I was wondering how to convert text similar to the following:

```
Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97
3.1 Definitions 98
3.2 Basic Properties 103
```

to:

```
("Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97" "#97")
("3.1 Definitions 98" "#98")
("3.2 Basic Properties 103" "#103")
```

by using some convenient yet powerful text manipulation languages and/or utilities such as sed, awk, regex, perl, python, ...

Thanks and regards!

---

Note:
In each line, the last number is repeated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    s/^(.+ (\d+))$/("$1" "#$2")/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97
3.1 Definitions 98
3.2 Basic Properties 103
```

prints:

```
("Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97" "#97")
("3.1 Definitions 98" "#98")
("3.2 Basic Properties 103" "#103")
```

or as a one liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.+ (\d+))$/("$1" "#$2")/'
```

Comment: Thanks! Note: In each line, the last number is repeated.

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with Perl. For the one liner solution, after hit return, it seems to expect me to paste the original text as input, and then I don't know how to tell it that I have finished the input.

Comment: @Tim => it would be easier to use shell redirection: `perl -pe '...' < input_file.txt > output_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of ways to do it using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.* \)\(.*\)/("\1\2" "#\2")/' inputfile
```

or

```
sed 's/\(.* \)\([0-9]*\)/("\1\2" "#\2")/' inputfile
```

Here's a couple using AWK:

```
awk '{n = $NF; print "(\"" $0 "\" \"#" n "\")"}' inputfile
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {q="\x22"} {n = $NF; print "(" q $0 q " " q "#" n q ")"}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python,

```
"Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97".rsplit(None,1)
```

gives

```
['Chapter 3 Convex Functions', '97']
```

Working with a block of text,

```
txt = """Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97
    3.1 Definitions 98
    3.2 Basic Properties 103"""

for line in txt.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip().rsplit(None,1)
    print('("{0} {1}" "#{1}")'.format(*line))
```

gives

```
("Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97" "#97")
("3.1 Definitions 98" "#98")
("3.2 Basic Properties 103" "#103")
```

**Edit:** I have updated it per your Note such that the page numbers are duplicated.

Comment: in Python - how else? what is the problem with this answer?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just clarifying. The questioner asked for an answer in "sed, awk, regex, perl, python, ..." and this answer didn't mention the language used.

Comment: Thanks! Note: In each line, the last number is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def format(str):
  m = re.search('(.*)\s(\d+)$', str)
  return "(\"" + m.group(1) + "\" \"#" +  m.group(2) + "\")"

print format('Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97')

print format('3.1 Definitions 98')

print format('3.2 Basic Properties 103')
```

returns

```
("Chapter 3 Convex Functions" "#97")
("3.1 Definitions" "#98")
("3.2 Basic Properties" "#103")
```

Comment: I would suggest moving `import re` out of your function body; also precompiling your regex.

Comment: Thanks! Note: In each line, the last number is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Works with pretty much every version of python

```
infile = open("input.txt")
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in infile:
    line, last = line.rstrip().rsplit(" ", 1)
    outfile.write('("%s %s" "#%s")\n' % (line, last, last))
```

Comment: @nightcracker: Thanks! How to output to another file?

Comment: @Tim: I'll edit the snippet as you wish, just tell me what you would prefer to enter on your terminal.

Comment: @nightcracker: I would like to have input from a file and output to another file. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim: Done. Edit filenames, save as somename.py and execute with `python somename.py`.

Comment: @nightcracker: Thanks! Just curious, how to modify the code to get rid of newline at the end of "last", so that the output and input are line-to-line correspondence, instead of one line in the input corresponds to three lines in the output?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not completely sure what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: After testing I think I know what you mean, edited code. Try it out :)

Comment: @nightcracker: Thanks!, But still some problem. I guess there is a newline at the end of "line", so there is one for "last" and each line in input corresponds to three lines in output.

Comment: Ahhh now I know what you mean, sorry, fixing.

Answer (score 1):

```
def munge(line):
    number = line.rsplit(None,1)[1]
    return '''("{0}" "#{1}")'''.format(line, number)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
pat = re.compile('^(.+?(\d+)) *$',re.M)

ch = '''Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97 
3.1 Definitions 98  
3.2 Basic Properties 103'''

print ch
print
print pat.sub('"\\1" "#\\2"',ch)
```

result

```
Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97 
3.1 Definitions 98  
3.2 Basic Properties 103

"Chapter 3 Convex Functions 97" "#97"
"3.1 Definitions 98" "#98"
"3.2 Basic Properties 103" "#103"
```